# Address form with country filter dropdown - google maps

Tags: autocomplete, maps, filtering, countries

I'm trying to add a "country" filter for an an autocomplete address form.
So when a user selects a certain country, the google autocomplete filters the address according to that country.
For some reason I cannot get the change event to happen when the user changes the country, and it seems to always just sit on "US".

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my my jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Elektra/2xucmqrL/33/

Here is the code to change filtering:

```
function initAutocomplete() {
// Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search predictions to
// geographical location types.
 autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
  document.getElementById('autocomplete'), {types: ['geocode'], 
componentRestrictions: countryRestrict});
  places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', onPlaceChanged);

  // Add a DOM event listener to react when the user selects a country.
  document.getElementById('country').addEventListener(
      'change', setAutocompleteCountry);

 // Set the country restriction based on user input.
// Also center and zoom the map on the given country.
function setAutocompleteCountry() {
  var country = document.getElementById('country').value;
  if (country == 'all') {
  autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': []});
//map.setCenter({lat: 15, lng: 0});
//map.setZoom(2);
  } else {
   autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': country});
//map.setCenter(countries[country].center);
//map.setZoom(countries[country].zoom);
  }
  clearResults();
  //clearMarkers();
}
```